# Saving AJAX / XHR State in AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) for Back Button Use

Tags: amp-html

I'm using the amp-form module to perform a page updated without a page reload.  It's working fine.  My search results are displayed to the user via an amp-mustache template.  **BUT** when the user clicks into a result and then later hits the ***back*** button the results are gone.  I need a way to save the state of the page.

So my question is: how can I make the back button show the same results the user originally had?  (hopefully without re-fetching).  I looked briefly at amp-bind but it says experimental.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported. A workaround is loading the search results in a new page. There are two ways to do this:

1. use a GET request in your amp-form or
2. [redirect after form submission](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-form/amp-form.md#redirecting-after-a-submission)

However, this sounds like a valid use case and I'd recommend filing a feature request for the AMP Runtime [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new).

Comment: Thanks Sabastian.  I'd rather not go to a new page.  Can you elaborate on #1?  How would GET help here?  Would that still be in-page update?  I don't mind having info on the URL--it's just search terms.

Comment: 1. would also open a new page. No way around this at the moment.